# JsonDeserializing a streamreader

Tags: c#, json, api, deserialization, webrequest

Im trying to deserlizer a streamreader (source from a webRequest) to then isert that json data to an object but the objets never get the data.

```
            WebRequest req = WebRequest.Create("API REQUEST HERE");
        WebResponse responde = req.GetResponse();

        StreamReader rd = new StreamReader(responde.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.ASCII);

        Summoner summo = new Summoner();
        JsonSerializer serializer = new JsonSerializer();
        JsonTextReader textrd = new JsonTextReader(rd);

        summo = serializer.Deserialize<Summoner>(textrd);
        summo.Ver();


        Console.ReadKey();
```

the json response is

```
{"amarasul":{"id":5560607,"name":"amarasul","profileIconId":787,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1439893886000}}
```

and the summoner.cs is

```
    public class Summoner
{

        public int id { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int profileIconId { get; set; }
        public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
        public long revisionDate { get; set; }


    public void Ver()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.id);
        Console.WriteLine(this.name);
        Console.WriteLine(this.profileIconId);
        Console.WriteLine(this.revisionDate);
        Console.WriteLine(this.summonerLevel);

    }
}
```

Comment: First of all - check the response status code. It could fail. You should receive status code 200

Comment: should i write 
    (int)responde.StatusCode
? cause its not working

Comment: Please post a sample JSON and the Summoner class

Comment: done, thanks i forgot it

Answer (score 0):

The problem is there is an extra layer in your JSON, an object called amarasul, which is not addressed.

If you change your Summoner class like the one below it should work just fine:

```
using System;

public class Summoner
{
    public Amarasul amarasul { get; set; }

    public void Ver()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(amarasul.id);
        Console.WriteLine(amarasul.name);
        Console.WriteLine(amarasul.profileIconId);
        Console.WriteLine(amarasul.revisionDate);
        Console.WriteLine(amarasul.summonerLevel);
    }
}

public class Amarasul
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int profileIconId { get; set; }
    public int summonerLevel { get; set; }
    public long revisionDate { get; set; }
}
```